# Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'

Tags: c#, listview

I have this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListView2.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("UcastCheckBox")).Checked || ((TextBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("BrankyTextBox")).ToString > 0)
           {

           }
        }
```

But now unchecked all checkboxs...:/

Can you idea how to solve it?

Comment: You are comparing `string` and `int` by the way..

Comment: .ToString is a method and it returns a string (so you cant compare that to 0 either).  I think you want !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mytextbox.Text)

Comment: I rolled back the edits to the question, since it was made into a completely different one, which no longer matched neither the title nor the answers. Bring up a new question for the new issue you're facing to be provided better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the string to int value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListView2.Items.Count; i++)
{
    int a;
    Int32.TryParse(((TextBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("BrankyTextBox")).ToString(), out a);

    if (((CheckBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("UcastCheckBox")).Checked ||
         a > 0)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: User input + `int.Parse` = exception

Comment: I agree, should definitely use `Int32.TryParse` (which has the added benefit in this case of setting the value to `0` on failure)

Comment: @sarwar026: The result now it this: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @Kate: can you try now please? I've update some little changes.

Comment: @sarwar026: i use your code with this : rol("UcastCheckBox")).Checked=false...but result is: all checkbox is uncheck.

Answer (score 1):

`ToString` is a method, and you are missing the parentheses, which are required to invoke the method, rather than merely refer to it. (This is the meaning of the error message that you posted.) I have extracted a couple variables to make the code more readable as well.

Also, as others have pointed out, you then must convert the string to an integer in order to compare it to `0`. You can use the `int.Parse` method for this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListView2.Items.Count; i++)
{
   var ucastCheckBox = (CheckBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("UcastCheckBox");
   var brankyTextBox = (TextBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("BrankyTextBox");

   // .ToString(), not .ToString
   // and int.Parse to get an int value from the string
   int brankyValue = int.Parse(brankyTextBox.ToString());

   if (ucastCheckBox.Checked || brankyValue > 0)
   {
   }
}
```

You should ideally use `int.TryParse` at some point to confirm that the value in the text box is an integer, but that is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: you must have used .ToString() before... your example wouldn't work

Comment: @Sahuagin: Input string was not in a correct format. int brankyValue = int.Parse(brankyTextBox.ToString());

Comment: @Kate yes, that is an error that you will get if there is not an integer value in the textbox. how to parse an integer is not a part of your question, however other users have indicated how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You compare a `string` with an `int`, you must cast the string value to int before comparing

try this

```
int a=int.Parse((((TextBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("BrankyTextBox")).ToString));
 if (((CheckBox)ListView2.Items[i].FindControl("UcastCheckBox")).Checked || a > 0 )
```

Comment: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'